# Why does System.Delegate implement ISerializable?

Tags: c#, delegates, iserializable

If you look at the sources for `System.Delegate` you'll see that it implements `ISerializable` interface:

```
[Serializable, ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual),__DynamicallyInvokable]
public abstract class Delegate : ICloneable, ISerializable
```

but the actual implementation throws an exception:

```
public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Why is `ISerializable` used; are there any derived types that actually *do* use serialization?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/81967491794ed15c.html

Comment: Binary serialization demands that the base class of a class that gets serialized is serializable as well.  But you never *actually* serialize an object of type Delegate, it is an abstract class.  You'll serialize a MulticastDelegate.  Which has an implementation for GetObjectData().

Comment: understood about the `MulticaseDelegate`. Are you saying you can binary serialize a delegate (multicasedelegate)?

Comment: Just try it.  Also the best way to find out why this is a feature that you should (almost) never use.